# How to move a directory in C# .NET in a single atomic operation

Tags: c#, .net, file, filesystems

I need to be able to move an entire directory in a single atomic operation, guaranteeing that nothing else on the system will be able to subvert the operation by creating new files after I start, having a lock on a file, etc.

Presumably, I would use System.IO.Directory.Move() if the directories were on the same volume (if Directory.GetDirectoryRoot() is the same), otherwise I'd have to create a new target directory on the other volume and recursively copy/move all the directories and files underneath.

Nothing I've read shows how to gain an exclusive lock to an entire directory leaf in .NET so this can be done safely. Is there a recommended/supported way to do this?

Comment: As an idea, may be you could try renaming the folder to a random name (GUID) before doing a recursive move...

Comment: @K J   If we want to move a folder to another path in the same volume, I agree with you. But I'm afraid it would not be the case if we're about to move a folder to another volume. In this case, we may temporarily rename the source folder as @Michael Todd suggested, but this approach may leave us a few edge cases we need to handle.

Answer (score 4):

Vista *does* support transactions in NTFS volumes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Could you work around this by renaming the "root" directory temporarily (creating a directory with the same name immediately thereafter so that anyone accessing that directory doesn't encounter an error), then work on the files in the renamed directory?

Answer (score 2):

I remember being able to do this at the DOS level by simply renaming the directory. There was a move command, which also seemed to work. But it makes sense. You're not really moving all of the files in the directory, you're just changing the meta data in the directory structure itself. I also remember this from hacking directory structures directly using a disk editor on my fathers Zenith Data Systems 8088. I could make directories invisible by changing the attribute bits on disk, even hiding ".." and "." and making subdirectories appear to be root (the parent directories were invisible). Hope this works for you. I haven't revisited this in hmmm too many years to count ;-). May it work for you.

---

By the way, you should not have to lock anything because if you're just renaming, it happens really fast, and it's just a single operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Transactional NTFS via PInvoke. Note that it's unclear if it works properly across different volumes, please [see the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefiletransactedw#return-value). You may need to use Distributed Transactions, which is [significantly more complicated](https://improve.dk/utilizing-transactional-ntfs-through-dotnet/). It will *only* work on NTFS volumes, not FAT.

Caveat: this code is entirely untested.

```cs
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, BestFitMapping = false)]
bool GetVolumeInformationW(
  [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
  string lpRootPathName,
  IntPtr lpVolumeNameBuffer,
  int nVolumeNameSize,
  out int lpVolumeSerialNumber,
  out int lpMaximumComponentLength,
  out int lpFileSystemFlags,
  IntPtr lpFileSystemNameBuffer,
  int nFileSystemNameSize
);

[DllImport("KtmW32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, BestFitMapping = false)]
private static extern SafeFileHandle CreateTransaction(
  IntPtr lpTransactionAttributes,
  IntPtr UOW,
  int CreateOptions,
  int IsolationLevel,
  int IsolationFlags,
  int Timeout,
  [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
  string Description
);

[DllImport("KtmW32.dll", SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false)]
private static extern bool CommitTransaction(SafeFileHandle hTransaction);

public enum ProgressResponse
{
    PROGRESS_CONTINUE,  // Continue the copy operation.
    PROGRESS_CANCEL,    // Cancel the copy operation and delete the destination file.
    PROGRESS_STOP,      // Stop the copy operation. It can be restarted at a later time.
    PROGRESS_QUIET,     // Continue the copy operation, but stop invoking CopyProgressRoutine to report progress.
}

public delegate ProgressResponse ProgressRoutine(
    long TotalFileSize,
    long TotalBytesTransferred,
    long StreamSize,
    long StreamBytesTransferred,
    int dwStreamNumber,
    int dwCallbackReason,
    IntPtr hSourceFile,
    IntPtr hDestinationFile,
    IntPtr lpData
);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, BestFitMapping = false)]
private static extern bool MoveFileTransactedW(
  [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
  string lpExistingFileName,
  [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
  string lpNewFileName,
  ProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine,
  IntPtr lpData,
  int dwFlags,
  SafeFileHandle hTransaction
);
```

```cs
private static bool CheckSupportsTransactions(string filePath)
{
    const int FILE_SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS = 0x00200000;
    if(!GetVolumeInformationW(
        Path.GetPathRoot(sourceFullPath),
        IntPtr.Zero, 0,
        out var _,
        out var _,
        out var flags,
        IntPtr.Zero, 0)
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

    return flags & FILE_SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS != 0;
}

public static void MoveDirectoryTransacted(string sourceFullPath, string destFullPath, ProgressRoutine progress = null)
{
    const int MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED = 0x2;
    const int ERROR_REQUEST_ABORTED = 0x4D3;
    sourceFullPath = Path.GetFullPath(sourceFullPath);
    destFullPath = Path.GetFullPath(destFullPath);
    if(!CheckSupportsTransactions(sourceFullPath) ||
       !CheckSupportsTransactions(destFullPath))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Volume does not support transactions");
    }

    using (var tran = CreateTransaction(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, null))
    {
        if (tran.IsInvalid)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        if (!MoveFileTransactedW(
            sourceFullPath,
            destFullPath,
            progress,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED,
            tran))
        {
            var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (error == ERROR_REQUEST_ABORTED)
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
            throw new Win32Exception(error);
        }

        if (!CommitTransaction(tran))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a `CancellationToken`, you could invoke it like this

```cs
MoveDirectoryTransacted("sourcePath", "destPath",
    () => cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested ? ProgressResponse.PROGRESS_CANCEL : ProgressResponse.PROGRESS_CONTINUE);
```

Comment: Your answer seems great. It works perfectly for moving any folder to the same destination volume. However, I got an "access denied" exception when I tried to move any folder to other volumes. Do you probably know the reason I got this exception, by any chance?

Comment: Not sure, I said it was unclear whether it worked. Maybe try as Admin?

Comment: It only works on NTFS I note, therefore not on SD cards and USB sticks unless formatted correctly. For multiple volumes you might need DTC, see also latest edit

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to run your copy process as "service account" that is only used by the copy process, you could set the permissions of the folder to only allow that account to work with it. Then reset the permissions back to what they were after the copy process finished.

For example, something like the following:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace ExclusiveLockFileCopy
{
    public class ExclusiveLockMover
    {
        public DirectorySecurity LockFolder(DirectoryInfo di)
        {
            var originalSecurity = di.GetAccessControl(System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections.All);
            //make sure inherted permissions will come back when UnlockFolder is called
            originalSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, true);

            var tmpSecurity = di.GetAccessControl(System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections.All);
            // remove all rules
            var currentRules = tmpSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
            foreach (AccessRule rule in currentRules)
            {
                tmpSecurity.PurgeAccessRules(rule.IdentityReference);
                tmpSecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.RemoveAll, rule, out var tmpModified);
                Console.WriteLine($"Removed access for {rule.IdentityReference.Value}");
            }

            //add back the current process' identity after the for loop - don't assume the account will show up in the current rule list (i.e. inherited access)
            var _me = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            var _meNT = new NTAccount(_me.Name);
            tmpSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(_meNT, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
            Console.WriteLine($"Ensuring {_meNT.Value} maintains full access");
            //strip out inherited permissions
            tmpSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);
            di.SetAccessControl(tmpSecurity);

            //send back the original security incase it is needed later for "unlocking"
            return originalSecurity;
        }
        public void UnlockFolder(DirectoryInfo di, DirectorySecurity originalSecurity)
            => di.SetAccessControl(originalSecurity);

        public void CopyFolderExclusive(string srcFolder, string dstFolder)
        {
            DirectorySecurity diSourceOriginalSecurity = null;
            DirectorySecurity diDestinationOriginalSecurity = null;

            var diSource = new DirectoryInfo(srcFolder);
            var diDestination = new DirectoryInfo(dstFolder);

            try
            {
                diSourceOriginalSecurity = LockFolder(diSource);

                if (!diDestination.Exists)
                    diDestination.Create();
                diDestinationOriginalSecurity = LockFolder(diDestination);

                // perform your folder/file copy here //

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (diSourceOriginalSecurity != null)
                    UnlockFolder(diSource, diSourceOriginalSecurity);

                if (diDestinationOriginalSecurity != null)
                    UnlockFolder(diDestination, diDestinationOriginalSecurity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say what you really need is a transactional file system... which NTFS ain't, and while there have been MS plans for such, it was cut from Longhorn before it became Vista (and from Cairo before that).

You could try to gain exclusive locks on every file in the directory before the move, and do the moving with explicit file reading/writing, but recursively? I'm not so sure that's a good idea... and besides, that won't protect against new files being added.

What are you really trying to do? Why are you worried about concurrent activity?